# Proving the surjectivity of a function

Tags: functions, elementary-set-theory

Proving the injectivity of a function starts with lines similar to the following:

> Assume that $f(x_{1}) = f(x_{2})$. If $x_{1} = x_{2}$, then $f$ is an injection.

Checking for the surjectivity of a function requires solving for the inverse and so on. Is there a similar way to prove the surjectivity of a function using a process similar to the one above?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Define $f : X \to Y$. Assume $y \in Y$. If you can show there exists at least one $x \in X$ such that $f(x) = y$, then you can show that $f$ is surjective.

Alternatively, say you define a function $g : Y \to X$. If you can show that $(f \circ g)(y) = y$ for all $y \in Y$, then $g$ is a right inverse to $f$, and thus surjective.

Alternatively, let $f^{-1}(B)$ denote the preimage of $B$, i.e. it is not an inverse, but rather

$$f^{-1}(B) = \{ x \in X \mid f(x) \in B \}$$

Then if for all $B \subseteq Y$ we have $f(f^{-1}(B)) =B$, then $f$ is surjective. Similarly, for all $B,C$ such that $B\subsetneq C \subseteq Y$, $f$ is surjective if $f^{-1}(B) \subsetneq f^{-1}(C)$.

All four of these are equivalent to surjectivity for a function $f$. Though, in my opinion, the first two are the main ones of utility.

Comment: So you mean to say that $f^{-1}(x)$ can be defined as a function, but not exactly the inverse of $f$?

Comment: $f^{-1}(x)$ can mean the preimage of $x$ under $f$. It is not necessarily a function, however, but rather it is a set, as I have described. Essentially, $f^{-1}(x)$ is the set of all points in $X$ that map to $x$. (I agree, the notation is somewhat confusing, but it is the conventional way to notate it.)

Comment: @kevs924 the preimage $f^{-1}(x)$ is suggestive of an inverse but it is a set, not a function. For a simple example consider the function $f: \mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ given by $f(x)=x^2$. The preimage of $4$ is $f^{-1}(4)=\{2,-2\}$ and of $-1$ is $f^{-1}(-1)=\emptyset$. Technically this should be written $f^{-1}(\{4\})$ but it is a common abuse of notation to leave off the braces for singletons.

Comment: Can I ask, how do you read it if it is not the inverse to avoid confusion?

Comment: Do you mean reading it aloud? If it were $f^{-1}(B)$, I would say "the preimage of $B$ (under $f$)."

Answer (score 3):

A function $f: X \to Y$ is surjective if and only if

> for each $y \in Y$ there is a $x \in X$, such that $f(x) = y$.

Let's consider an example. Let $f: \mathbb R \to \mathbb R$ be defined as
$$f(x) = 2x + 1 \; .$$
We want to show that $f$ is surjective. So let $y \in \mathbb R$ be arbitrary. We need to find a $x \in \mathbb R$, such that $f(x) = y$. So the equation
$$2x + 1 = y$$
must hold for this to be true.
Solving this equation for $x$ gives
$$
x = \frac{y-1}{2} \; .
$$
Now we are done: For $y \in \mathbb R$ we choose
$$
x = \frac{y-1}{2} \; ,
$$
then
$$
f(x) = f\left(\frac{y-1}{2}\right) = 2 \cdot \frac{y-1}{2} + 1 = y - 1 + 1 = y \; .
$$

Answer (score 1):

Another way for proving surjectivity or onto is by $\forall b \in B \space \exists a \in A [f(a) = b]$

So an example would be $f(x) = 2x+1$ where $f: \mathbb R \rightarrow \mathbb R$.
$$\text{Let $b$ be an arbitrary number in the codomain.} \\ \text{Let $a = \frac{b-1}{2}$} \\ f(a) = 2a +1 \\ f(a) = 2 (\frac{b-1}{2}) +1 \\ f(a) = b-1+1 \\ f(a) = b \\ \text{Since $b$ is arbitrary we can say this function is surjective.}$$

Comment: Remember that a function always needs an explicit domain and codomain. Your proof fails for $\text{codomain f}=\mathbb{R}$ and $\text{domain f}=\mathbb{R}\setminus \{0\}$

Comment: Added! Thank you! New to proof writing.